# Knockout Validation and Twitter Bootstrap Error CSS

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, knockout.js

I am trying to integrate knockout validation and twitter bootstrap in this editor: http://jsfiddle.net/casudeo/Jbp7y/18

I'd like to apply twitter bootstrap's css for input errors. To do that, I would need to somehow "walk up" to the control-group div and add an 'error' class to it. Is there a way to achieve this without modifying the css files?

Additional clarification because of dominik's comment below:
1) Click the "Add" button to add a new item. 
2) Try to save with blank values. 
3) KO validation will catch invalid inputs. However, I would also like to apply an "error" css class to highlight invalid fields.

Comment: I don't see the connection between your twitter-bootstrap problem and this list of Jim and Bob... please be more specific.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is an updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jearles/Jbp7y/147/

HTML

```
<div><button data-bind="click: clickMe">Click Me!</button></div>
```

JS

```
var ViewModel = function() {
    var self = this;
    self.clickMe = function(data,event) {
      var target;

      if (event.target) target = event.target;
      else if (event.srcElement) target = event.srcElement;

      if (target.nodeType == 3) // defeat Safari bug
        target = target.parentNode;

      target.parentNode.innerHTML = "something";
    }
}

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

The things I changed:

1. Add 'validationElement' bindings to the control-group divs
2. Add a call to 'showAllMessages()' when errors are detected
3. Ensure the errorElementClass configuration is set to 'error'

Comment: This is perfect!  Works great!  Is there an easy way to add the "success" bootstrap class when an item passes validation?  This would make the field turn "green" when the user has fulfilled the rules on that field.